# Equation number referral doesn't appear within the empheq/array environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, numbering, empheq

Why doesn't the equation number referral appear within the `empheq/array` environment ?
In this example I left out the formulas within the `empheq` environment (the problem remains with the formulas added).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}{align}
\label{eq:1}
\left\{\!\!\begin{array}{l}
\text{An equation reference should appear after the question mark, but doesn't ? \eqref{eq:2}}\\
\text{This doesn't work either : \eqref{eq:2}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{empheq}

I can definitely refer to the equation though, like this : \eqref{eq:2}.

\begin{empheq}{align}
\label{eq:2}
1+1=2
\end{empheq}


It compiles without throwing an error.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to compile the document twice.  First time a `(??)` is displayed, upon subsequent run, the equation number will appear.

Comment: I did - makes no difference.

Comment: Nothing is displayed, not even the (??).

Comment: And do **not** remove the temporary files generated during the first run.

Comment: I didn't remove anything, as I said, it doesn't throw up any error, but does not work.

Comment: Oppss, sorry. I was looking at the wrong spot in your output -- seems to be an issue with `empheq`.

Comment: How can this issue be fixed ?

Comment: Overlooked it because of missing tags, `empheq` tag added, problem noted.

Comment: Hmm, that is a tough one. It is because `\maketag@@@` is redefined inside the body of `empheq` in order to separate the math and the eqn numbers. But `\maketag@@@` is also used internally inside `\eqref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem goes away if you use `(\ref{whatever})` in place of `\eqref{whatever}`. I have no idea why this happens, though.

Comment: Works, but does not retain the brackets, but these can be added separately. THX.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that `empheq` redefines `\maketag@@@` because it need to separate the display from the eqn numbers. But `\eqref` also make use of this macro to typeset the reference to an eqn numbers. The fix below seem to do the trick and will be build into the next `empheq` release

```
\makeatletter
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\renewenvironment{empheq}[2][]{%
  \let\savedmaketag\maketag@@@
  \renewcommand\eqref[1]{\textup{%
      \let\maketag@@@\savedmaketag%
      \tagform@{\ref{##1}}}%
  }
  \setkeys{EmphEqEnv}{#2}\setkeys{\EQ_options_name:}{#1}%
  \EmphEqMainEnv}{\endEmphEqMainEnv}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```